# Radio button checked value on revisiting the page

Tags: jquery, html

```
<div class="formfield ship">
    <input type="radio" class="ship1" name="1" >1</input>
    <input type="radio" class="ship2" name="1" >2</input>
    <input type="radio" class="ship3" name="1" >3</input>
    <div class="clear"><!-- FLOAT CLEAR --></div>
</div>
```

I have radio buttons one must have the default value.. when I pick one and submit and then I go back to the page the value must retain..

any idea how can I do it?

Comment: What default value?  Is one of these supposed to be "selected" in the markup?  Define "go back to the page."  If you have server-side code rendering the page, can it render the elements in the state that they were submitted?  Where does jQuery come into this?

Comment: Is your HTML generated server-side, or is it just a static HTML page?

Comment: the first radio button is checked already on the first load of the page.

Comment: go back button of the browser where the value that was picked must be retained

Comment: example is the default radio button is 1 and when I checked 2 and submit the form. and when I go back to edit it the value must still be 2 and not the default value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this does what you want - although you need to modify your html slightly (I don't think `<input></input>` is valid)

http://jsfiddle.net/malet/dvCpj/6/

```
$("input[type=radio]").each(function(){
    $(this).click(function(){     
        createCookie($(this).attr("name"), $($(this).siblings()[0]).html(),1);       
    });
});


$(document).ready(function(){
    $("input[type=radio]").each(function(){
        var selected = readCookie($(this).attr("name"));
        if(selected != null){
            if($($(this).siblings()[0]).html() == selected){
                $(this).attr("checked","checked");
            }                    
        }    
    });
});


function createCookie(name,value,days) {
    if (days) {
            var date = new Date();
            date.setTime(date.getTime()+(days*24*60*60*1000));
            var expires = "; expires="+date.toGMTString();
    }
    else var expires = "";
    document.cookie = name+"="+value+expires+"; path=/";
}

function readCookie(name) {
    var nameEQ = name + "=";
    var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
    for(var i=0;i < ca.length;i++) {
            var c = ca[i];
            while (c.charAt(0)==' ') c = c.substring(1,c.length);
            if (c.indexOf(nameEQ) == 0) return c.substring(nameEQ.length,c.length);
    }
    return null;
}

function eraseCookie(name) {
    createCookie(name,"",-1);
}
​
```

Answer (score 0):

Client side you would want to use a cookie to store the information. Server side, you can use session variables.

It depends on your environment, but you are basically saving what the user submits and checking that value when you output the form.

Answer (score 0):

Basically there is two way you can do this.

1. Cookies
2. Server Side Languages like php, asp

But either way, the main point is that, the default values of the radio elements have to be changed. You can use, serverside script to give the new default or use cookies to fetch the new defaults.